# Laravel Deployer cloning repo git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: laravel, git, ssh, deployment

I have a problem with linking a ssh key to a repository on github.

I have a project on WSL in the Laravel framework that I want to flip to VPS. For deploy I am using the Laravel Deployer package.

As instructed, I generated a public/private key set using ssh-keygen. In WSL /home/deployer/.ssh/config I have:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_deployer
```

On the VPS, I added the public ssh-rsa key to /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys. At this stage everything is ok, it authorises itself to the VPS and all the tasks from `vendor/bin/dep provision -o become=root` are running. A file structure is created at the designated location.

According to the instructions, the next step is to run `vendor/bin/dep deploy -o become=root` and here unfortunately I stop at the `deploy:update_code` task (the task is directly from the Laravel Deployer package):

```
task deploy:info
[some-page] info deploying HEAD
task deploy:setup
  ⠙ r passphrase for key '/home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa_deployer':   ⠧
task deploy:lock
task deploy:release
task deploy:update_code
[some-page]  error  in update_code.php on line 90:
[some-page] run export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT='0' GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new'; [ -f /var/www/project-name/.dep/repo/HEAD ] || /usr/bin/git clone --mirror git@github.com:my-name/my-repo.git /var/www/project-name/.dep/repo 2>&1
[some-page] Cloning into bare repository '/var/www/project-name/.dep/repo'...
[some-page] git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
[some-page] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[some-page] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[some-page] and the repository exists.
[some-page] exit code 128 (Invalid exit argument)
ERROR: Task deploy:update_code failed!
task deploy:failed
task deploy:unlock
```

When I access the deployer user via PuTTy with the same key as I have on WSL I have no problem cloning the repository: `git clone --mirror git@github.com:my-name/my-repo.git` . On the VPS in /home/deployer/.ssh/config I have:

```
Host github.com
    AddKeyToAgent yes
    ForwardAgent yes
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The /home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa was generated inside the VPS using ssh-keygen.

Of course, I added the deployer public keys from the WSL (id_rsa_deployer) and the one generated inside the VPS (/home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa) to my github account under Settings -> SSH and GPG keys.

I might also add that I don't have an SSL certificate on the VPS, but I doubt it would make any difference.

I would be grateful for any help, if needed I can send additional information.

Comment: Did you add the public key or the private key?

Comment: Yes that was both public rsa ssh keys. I must missing some part on my wsl part when I'm doing deploy, but have no clue.